# Has IOS13 broken <audio> tags used as audio buffers connected to the audio context?

Tags: web-audio-api, ios13

We are currently developing a website that allows users to play simple audio tags connected to the audiocontext. We are aware of technical issues with IOS such as playback initiated by user gestures. Everything is working fine up to IOS12.
Now that IOS13 is out, nothing works anymore.

It works on all desktops, android and IOS up to IOS13.

Any idea on what is going on?

There are no error messages in the console when debugging with Safari on Desktop connected to the iphone.

https://codepen.io/gchad/pen/WNNvzzd

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<body>

<div>
  <h1>Play Audio Tag connected to audio context</h1>
  <div id="playbutton" style="width:100px; height:100px; background:blue; color:white; margin:auto; text-align: center; font-size: 30px; cursor: pointer;">
    Play
  </div>

  <audio  id="myPlayer" crossorigin="anonymous" >
    <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/858/outfoxing.mp3"/>
      <!--http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/week7-brrring.m4a-->
  </audio> 
</div>

<script>

var player = document.getElementById('myPlayer'),
playbutton = document.getElementById('playbutton'),
playStatus = 'paused';

var audioContext = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var audioSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(player); 
audioSource.connect(audioContext.destination); 

playbutton.addEventListener('click',function(ev){

  if( playStatus == 'paused'){

    audioContext.resume();
    player.play();
    playbutton.innerHTML = "Pause";
    playStatus = 'isPlaying';

  } else {

      player.pause();
      playbutton.innerHTML = "Play";
      playStatus = 'paused';
  }
});
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Mine app has been broken as well. But I see you create audio context before click, it was not allowed in ios 12 too.

Comment: The `audioContext.resume();` line should take care of that, but I think what follows should be in the promise resolve, like this:

    audioContext.resume().then(function () {
        player.play()
        playbutton.innerHTML = "Pause";
        playStatus = 'isPlaying';
    }

Comment: I already added the promise in the codepen. But with or without promise, it does change anything.

Comment: I have the same problem. Only difference is the audio tag is dynamically rendered in a single page app. I got it partially working by making the `src` static with a full URL. However, it only works if you leave Safari and then open it again. Very strange behavior.

Comment: unfortunately even with iOS < 13 making use of createMediaElementSource often showed unpleasant artifacts like distortion. Reported about a year ago - hopefully this will be fixed together with the current issue. For now we'll have to restrict functionality for Safari users, as desktop seems to no longer work as well.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, `AudioContext.createMediaElementSource` has been broken since the release of iOS 13. The bug was reported to be fixed in [Safari Technology Preview 99](https://webkit.org/blog/9992/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-99/): https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203435, but it's still broken in the recent release of iOS, so a new bug report was filed which can be found here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=211394

Comment: It looks like the devs from webkit fixed it a few days ago, however, I'm still experiencing the problem on the latest iOS version. Is it going to be fixed with the next ios release or webkit release? I'm confused.

Comment: @Umbrella I've edited my answer with the latest updates.

Answer (score 3):

This issue was mistakenly reported as fixed in iOS 13.3.1 (January 28, 2020). Nevertheless, as anyone can read from this [WebKit bug report 203435](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203435), the problem is still there as of April 7, 2020, the release date of iOS 13.4.1.

The bug report doesn't provide any further information in regards to the estimated date this bug is going to be fixed. Sadly, 80% of iOS users (about 14% of the total mobile market, according to Statcounter) have been mistakenly incapacitated from using WebAudio on their devices for months, now.

What makes things worse for us developers is that Safari doesn't report any error. Thus, even trying to imagine a fallback is not possible or very hard, anyway.

Comment: The only way to implement a reasonable fallback is to use `AudioBufferSourceNode` and  implement streaming yourself, so you don't need to use `createMediaElementSource`. This however has the downside, that using an AudioElement also makes a few iOS features available like playback while the phone is muted or show the currently playing track on the lock screen. I wish I had a good idea to make a fallback work without resorting to a native app.