# Audio doesn't play anymore in Safari 13 unless getUserMedia is called

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm recording audio using `getUserMedia`, then allowing the user to click a button to listen to either the recording or another buffer. This has all worked fine for a year, so I don't think I'm violating any of the rules that cause AudioContext to be suspended. And, anyway, I'm testing the AudioContext to make sure it isn't suspended in my button handler.

This has all been working fine on all modern systems with many browsers. However, this is not playing the audio in Safari 13 in iOS. It will return from the promises as if it were playing audio, but nothing sounds until I call `getUserMedia` again.

As an experiment, I put the following line on the top of my button handler:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: {
        echoCancellation: {ideal: false},
    }
});
```

And it works!

But, why? I'm not comfortable with that solution because I'm not sure why the browser wants that. It doesn't make sense to me that I'd have to request the microphone to play any sound.

The only clue I have is that once I do the `getUserMedia` I keep the recording open on Safari (I do that because Safari has a time out - when I request the mic, it pops up a dialog to the user to allow the mic. Sometimes it might take the user 90 seconds to get around to pressing "record", and if I don't leave the mic open it pops up the dialog again.)

Anyone have any idea what is going on? And, I haven't been able to find any technical write up of Safari and audio. Is there anything beyond the standard MDN?

Answer (score 1):

IOS13 also broke one of our applications. It's been working fine for years. No errors are thrown and we are not violating any rules. Here is the link to my post:
[Has IOS13 broken <audio> tags used as audio buffers connected to the audio context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58306894/has-ios13-broken-audio-tags-used-as-audio-buffers-connected-to-the-audio-conte)

Even though it is a different use of the api, I believe it is related. Apple clearly broke something on this new release.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like the same symptoms. I filed a bug report w/Apple and I'll post any more info I get.

Comment: Where can I file such report? (the more we are the better)

Comment: hi @Paulie did you hear anything back from apple? It breaks our app as well.

Answer (score 0):

This was confirmed to be a bug in Safari 13 and was fixed in a maintenance release. We haven't heard any more reports from the field so I guess it auto updated for everyone.